# active record ignores new attribute in migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When I'm creating a new column through a migration helper and setting the value through ruby-active-record-model-code. even through the changes are valid and the ruby object data looks good the new attribute is not saved through ActiveRecord after all.

Thats what i'm doing in detail:

I'm adding the new column to my schema for the user model:

```
add_column :users, :billing_day_of_month, :integer
```

right after this, also in my migration file, I want to fill this new column following a simple ruby formula:

```
User.customers.each do |u|
  day = nil

  if u.last_charged_at
    day = u.last_charged_at.day 
  else 
    day = u.plan_started_at.day
  end

  u.billing_day_of_month = day

  puts "precheck #{u.id} #{u.valid?}"

  if u.save
    puts "saved #{u.id} -> #{u.billing_day_of_month}"
  else
    puts "not saved #{u.errors.inspect}"
  end
end
```

All out*puts* look very promising:

```
precheck 399 true
saved 399 -> 22
precheck 414 true
saved 414 -> 9
precheck 203 true
saved 203 -> 8
precheck 439 true
saved 439 -> 21
```

Unfortunately, the values in the model are not being saved via ActiveRecord:

```
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = $1 WHERE "users"."id" = $2  [["updated_at", "2016-01-15 13:01:04.966681"], ["id", 399]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = $1 WHERE "users"."id" = $2  [["updated_at", "2016-01-15 13:01:04.969648"], ["id", 414]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = $1 WHERE "users"."id" = $2  [["updated_at", "2016-01-15 13:01:04.972547"], ["id", 203]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = $1 WHERE "users"."id" = $2  [["updated_at", "2016-01-15 13:01:04.975492"], ["id", 439]]
```

So I digged around and found that `User.attribute_names` is missing the new attribute name `billing_day_of_month`. When I use the rails console after this migration, the  `User.attribute_names` **does** contain the new attribute name.

Btw at the time of migration, the schema.rb does contain the new column.

*Anyone have a clue what I'm missing here? - I already used new cols within the same migration through a model and it always worked.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `User.reset_column_information` before the update loop. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reset_column_information for more details.